# Cannot connect Drupal SMTP from Acquia to AWS SES

Tags: emails, acquia-cloud

We have a Drupal system running on acquia platform and was using smtp for the mail connection. Previously we were using gmail account to sent the mail and was working fine. But now as per the requirement from the client side, we are trying to connect with AWS SES mail system from Drupal using SMTP. But unfortunately that didn't work.

We had enabled the smtp mode on the AWS SES and added an email  on the verified mail list. Also created password for smtp. Then we used this credentials in Drupal smtp config form. But mail sending is not working.

The Drupal side, it is showing the connect authentication issue. And on the AWS SES side, we are seeing the bounce mail reports. So we are aware that the connection is not blocked anywhere.

Please find the details that we used in Drupal as part of smtp configuration:

- SMTP server: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
- SMTP port: 465
- Use encrypted protocol: TLS
- Enable TLS encryption automatically: On
- Timeout: 30
- Turn on the SMTP keep alive feature: Checked
- Username: smtp username
- Password: smtp password
- E-mail from address: smtp verified mail id
- E-mail from name: Support Team
- Allow to send e-mails formatted as HTML: Checked

Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you confirmed outside of Drupal that you are able to send email with that platform? It would help to show us the actual error messages.

Comment: Thanks @cilefen , No I didn't. I will try in plain php script and update the result here